# Facebook Toolkit, send messages to users wall

Tags: .net, facebook

I need to send messages on users wall or friends wall, I know how to post messages on my wall but how to post messages to another user wall??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to send to another user's wall - is absolutely the same as to send on current user's wall: with using Stream.publish

just specify `target_id` with needed user's id ;-)

Comment: but how I can get the user's id without connect to his account??

Comment: huh? how do you determine "another user" from your question? do you know anything specific about that "another user"? the only possible way to post to non-current user's wall is: 1) to get active user to be ligged in (this user will be the author of post) 2) to know `user_id` of another user.

Comment: I know user name and password of this "another user"

Comment: if you have no any active session or current user have no access to post to "another user"'s wall - you cannot post there. and password wouldn't help in any case.

Comment: ok, but what is the key to post messages on this user wall?? how to obtain this permissions? To post message on my wall I don't need any extended permissions, maybe I need to add my FB application to user's page??

Comment: again: for posting to another user's wall you need: 1) active session 2) to know target user's id 3) access to posting to user's 2 wall by user 1.

Comment: I add my application to users profile and it's working now, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this... ñ_ñ

```
            try
        {
            String namePub = servicio.Users.GetInfo().first_name + "ha actualizado su estado";
            String cosa = servicio.Stream.Publish(richTextBox1.Text,
            new attachment()
            {
                name = namePub,
                href = "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=136818146334647",
                caption = "Tú tambien puedes usar Escuchando ahora, es facil y rapido",
                properties = null,
                media = new List<attachment_media>()
                {
                    new attachment_media_image()
                    {
                        src="http://www.rammsdio.com.ar/images/img14781001.gif",
                        href = "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=136818146334647"
                    }
                }
            },
            new List<action_link>() 
            {
                new action_link()
                {
                    text="Visita SQLeros",
                    href="http://www.sqleros.com.ar/wps"
                }
            }, stringId, 0);
            listBox1.Items.Add("Has actualizado tu estado...");
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
                servicio.Stream.AddLike(cosa);
        }
        catch (FacebookException fb)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(fb.Message);
        }
```